# How to force state server to throw away all sessions?

Tags: asp.net, session, iis, session-cookies

I have an asp.net web app which uses state server to store its sessions. When we change a type of something which is stored in the session, all users with active sessions got error, beacuse the "old session" contains insrtances of "old type".

I thought that the simplest way to overcome this problem would be to restart the state server, therefor get rid of all sessions. However, this was proffed to be a naive approach. Sessions seems to be still active (users with session old cookie are still capable of working). **Is there some other way to force the session state server throw away all sessions, so that old users will be assigned new session?** It is ok if they would be forced to authenticate again.

**Or is there some other (better) way of abandoning all sessions? Ideally not programmaticaly, but something our admin could do?**

**Programmatical approach woudl be maybe calling `Session.RemoveAll` in `Application_End` would solve the issue, bu is this standard approach?**

**Where are session stored in state server if not in memory (which should cease to exist on restart)?**

I have found two SO questions which are relevant:

[Clear all sessions on application start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417587/clear-all-sessions-on-application-start) - this is rather incomplete programmatical solution

[How to clear SQL session state for all users in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321435/how-to-clear-sql-session-state-for-all-users-in-asp-net) - this is exactly what I would needed if I had had an sql server approach of storing of session data

Comment: Possibly changing you machine key could help, but i'm not sure about that.

Comment: @Grumbler85, thanks nice idea. Unfortunatelly, it is a no go as we are using SSO among other apps, which we would have to change as well.

Comment: Well SSO consist of multiple Cookies (as seen in ADFS) 1 for Login-Server, and one for each application - the latter are Independent in normal cases, so you could invalidate them - or you have to write some code, which makes them invalid by checking their issue-time. I don't see another way for admins here...

Comment: We use simple SS, which relies on machinekey to be same on all apps. Basically first aprt of this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, So it seems so (after a bit of experimenting), that restarting of the session state server throw away all data in the session.

The users still have their session ID valid after restart though, which got me originally thinking that the session is not thrown away.

I guess that if the session id sent from a user is not assigned to some existing session, than it is reused for the new one, so user still operates with the same id. Nevertheless, the data in session are cleared.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question but a clean programmatic workaround could be to wrap access to `Session` and try to be smart and detect issues:

```
// example
public string SomethingWrapper
{ 
   try
   {
       return (string)Session["something"];
   } 
   catch
   {
       return "defaultvalue";   
   }
}
```

This should work for value objects and composite objects too. If the deserializer fails for a compound object, you get an exception and have a chance to return just anything, a default value for example. Or you can recreate the value and put it back into session container.

Comment: Thanks WIktor +1 for your input. You are right, that if I would go with some programmatical solution, yours would be good to consider. I am mostly looking for a solution for admin and aslo for answering why the state server after restart still keeps the sessions (or recreates them?)