# IIS changing physical paths between two folders should cause web app session to expire

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I have a ASP .NET MVC web app on a windows server, on the server I have two folders; one for development/staging and one for production.

I first publish it to the development folder and test it there. After testing it there I go in to IIS and I change the physical path of the production folder to reference the development/staging folder.

When I login to the web app under that exists in the production folder after I change the physical path the expected behavior is that I would be logged out of the app since the session should now be different. That is not the case however, currently the user stays logged in even after changing the physical path of the production site.

I'm not sure why this behavior changed and was wondering if anyone can provide some insight. Nothing has changed in either the web app or IIS that would affect this.

Comment: Why are you using the production environment as a test environment? Why have two environments if you will use them as a single one? You should consider using an appropriate deployment plan

Comment: "The expected behavior is that I would be logged out of the app since the session should now be different." That's your "expected" but not what we "expected". Sessions are not associated with physical path of a site.

Comment: Good read will be "State Server Mode"(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21457165/how-to-force-state-server-to-throw-away-all-sessions